# Define the name of the input parameter

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm submiting some data (`Collection<Cars>`) with JQuery by AJAX but now I don't know how to define the object in my Action input parameter. I already tried to define as **FormCollection** and I received all data. However what I really want is to define as **`ICollection<Car>`** but when I do this my object **cames to null**. How can I do this? Or how can I **parse a FormCollection** to a `ICollection<Car>`?

**My controller:**

```
public ActionResult UpdateTable(ICollection<Car> collection)
{
//some code
}
```

**My js:**

```
function updateTable(tableId) {
        if (tableId == "myTable") 
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            if ($("#" + tableId + " tbody tr").length % 2 == 0)

                var myTableData = $("#" + tableId).find("select, input").serializeObject();

            $.post("../../Car/UpdateTable/", myTableData , function(partial) {
                $("#myOtherTable tbody").append(partial);
            });
        }
    }

$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

**Car.cs:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
public bool IsSold { get; set; }
```

**Results:**

What comes to action controller when input parameter is `ICollection<Car>`: **null**

What comes to action controller when input parameter is `FormCollection` (in AllKeys):

```
Car[0].Id
Car[0].Name
Car[0].Owners
IsSold
```

**My view (row table):**

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new { Name = modelFieldInitialName + "Id", id = modelFieldInitialId + "Id" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { Name = modelFieldInitialName + "Name", id = modelFieldInitialId + "Name" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Owners, new SelectList(TempData["OwnersList"] as IEnumerable, "Id", "Description"), "", new { Name = modelFieldInitialName + "Owners", id = modelFieldInitialId + "Owners" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owners)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSold, new { type = "checkbox", Name = modelFieldInitialName + "IsSold", id = modelFieldInitialId + "IsSold" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsSold)
        </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: have you tried to sending a Json?

Comment: @Guillelon how can I do that? I never worked with JSON

Comment: cant u post part of ur html table and ur car class definition

Comment: @NitinVarpe I don't understand how can that help. The HTML table is inside a form on a partialView listing all cars in the model and imagine that the Car.cs has an id, a name, a list of something, whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after much looking and try my code, I finally discovered the problem:

If we send a model type of `CarStand` (for example) which include a `ICollection<Car>` to the view, on a case like this where we are building a dynamic table (and defining elements names and ids), to receive something different from a `FormCollection` we can't expect the controller receive the `ICollection<Car>`.

Model passed to the view (**CarStand.cs**):

```
public ICollection<Car> Cars{ get; set; }
//other properties
```

But we can send/post to the controller the whole model passed to the view, but with the selected data we need. So, it's done like this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateTable(CarStand collection)
{
//some code
}
```

And the JQuery could stay like before:

```
function updateTable(tableId) {
        if (tableId == "myTable") 
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            if ($("#" + tableId + " tbody tr").length % 2 == 0)

                var myTableData = $("#" + tableId).find("select, input").serializeObject();

            $.post("../../Car/UpdateTable/", myTableData , function(partial) {
                $("#myOtherTable tbody").append(partial);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had got in similar situation few days back I am posting my solution.

I am supposing that ur table look like this.

```
<table id="partTable">
<tr>
    <td class="cell">Nitin</td>
    <td class="desc">Varpe</td>
    <td class="desc">8881</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">Parag</td>
    <td class="desc">Lombar</td>
    <td class="desc">4999</td>
</tr>

</table>
<div>
<input type="button" id="sendRequest" value="send" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#sendRequest').click(function (e) {
        PostTable();
    });


    // Read a row
    function GetRow(rowNum) {
        var tableRow = $('#partTable tr').eq(rowNum);

        var row = {};

        row.FirstName = tableRow.find('td:eq(0)').text();
        row.LastName = tableRow.find('td:eq(1)').text();
        row.RollNumber = tableRow.find('td:eq(2)').text();


        return row;
    }

    // Read all rows
    function GetAllRows() {
        var dataRows = [];

        $('#partTable tr').each(function (index, value) {
            var currentRow = GetRow(index);
            dataRows.push(currentRow);
        });

        return dataRows;
    }

    // POST rows to server
    function PostTable() {
        //var crossId = getParameterByName('id');
        var jsonRequest = { rows: GetAllRows()};

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonRequest),
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
            //ur logic after success                
              return true;
            },
            error:function (ts){
            alert(ts.responseText);
                return false;
                }

                });
            } 

    </script>
```

Here is the class.

```
public class Row
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string RollNumber { get; set; }

    }
```

Action to call

```
public ActionResult GetRows(List<Row> rows)
        {
           //your logic

            return Json(new
            {
                list = object
            });

        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So basically you send a `JSON.stringify(jsonRequest)` object and the controller recognizes that like a `List<Row>`. But still seems strange to me my code does not work because `serializeObject()` or just `serialize()` have the same behavior as the `JSON.stringify()`. Also, your code does not seem a good practice because there is no dynamism. If you have 100 fields in the rows table you'll have to do this several times and you cann't join or take code from your table without having to also make changes in your JScript

Comment: I have other question: why you do this code? If I understand your code, you could to use `serilize()`. See [this link](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-and-when-to-use-jquerys-serialize-method/)

Comment: I was going to have dynamic table, whose rows were going to be created dynamically